# Using Jquery/Javascript to send imgsrc value to hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a user form where people can update their details and it saves to the database.

I have added the function for people to upload an avatar, crop the image and upload it to the server (using Cropper).

When the user has finished cropping their image the script updates the HTML and replaces the default avatar with their new one, as below:

```
<div class="avatar-view" title="" data-original-title="Change the avatar">
  <img src="../../scripts/cropper/img/20150728143117.png" alt="Avatar">
</div>
```

Underneath the avatar is the user form with the rest of the details and a save/submit button. I have added a hidden field for the avatar, but I need to send the value of the newly uploaded image to this hidden field. I have looked for various pieces of javascript/jquery to do this but I can't seem to get it to work so far.

```
<form id="reg-form" name="r_form" method="post" action="/editor/go/user" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="avatar">avatar</label>
                <input type="hidden" name="avatar" value="123">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="first_name"><i class="fa fa-star icon-red"></i> First name</label>
                <input id="first_name" name="first_name" class="form-control" value="John">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="last_name"><i class="fa fa-star icon-red"></i> Last name</label>
                <input id="last_name" name="last_name" class="form-control" value="Smith">
            </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="form_submit" tabindex="15">Save</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="41">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add an id to the hidden input value,

```
<input id="avatar-val" type="hidden" name="avatar" value="123">
```

then execute this code when the button is clicked

```
$("#avatar-val").val($(".avatar-view>img").prop('src'));
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding this to the bottom of my page but it makes the page appear blank and my code editor says there is a syntax error

Comment: not sure what is the issue, as this properly works for me. Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mog6qb78/) . Note that I have made the hidden input to text just to see it working. You can change it back to hidden and check it using inspect element too. You can make the button type to `button` instead of `submit` to see the result without submitting the form.

Comment: @Rob88991 anyways what is the error in the console?

Comment: I can't see the jquery on that fiddle or am I just being dumb? Sorry.

Comment: Oops I am really sorry, I just edited the link on my comment. Click the link again :D

Comment: @Rob88991 did you get it working? In your own project have you also included jquery.min.js script?

Comment: I copied it exactly as it is in your link but the page still appears blank, and I do have jquery loaded. I'm not sure if its confiscating with something else, very strange.

Comment: Oops. What is the exact error you see in the console?!

Comment: No error in the console, everything is blank, html included.

Comment: Sorry, working now! Something strange going on there but I moved the script to a different place in the footer. Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: Hehe really glad to hear that and also to help you! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Get the link to current image using query and set it to hidden field.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="avatar">avatar</label>
     <input type="hidden" name="avatar" value="123">
</div>
<script>
    var src = $('.avatar-view').find('img').attr('src');
    $('input[name="avatar"]').attr('src', src)
</script>
```

Comment: $('input[name="avatar"]').value(src);

Answer (score 0):

Your `img` tag needs to have an id. Then you can simply use the [DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_src.asp) to change the `src`. Then you can tie a Javascript function to the `onclick` attribute of the `submit` button.

```
<img id="change" src = "....">
...
<button type="submit" onclick="changeImage()" class="btn btn-primary" name="form_submit" tabindex="15">Save</button>

<script>
function changeImage(){
    src = document.getElementById("change").src ;
    document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value - src;
}
</script>
```

Comment: What do I need to change the value to on the hidden field?

Comment: 2 ways. Way 1(No changes to HTML needed): Add this to the JS function `document.getElementsByName("user_id")[0].value = "...";`. Way 2: Give the hidden value an Id and do the same thing as in my code example.

Comment: @Rob88991 I edited my answer. I misunderstood the question originally.

Answer (score 0):

Without any modification you can use like

```
   var src=$('img[alt="Avatar"]').attr('src');
   $('input:hidden[name=avatar]').val(src);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, its telling me there are syntax errors also.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $('#reg-form').submit(function() {
         var newSrc = $('#ID_of_your_img').attr('src');
         $('[name=avatar]').val(newSrc);
     });

});
```

I hope this will help you. if you face any issue feel free to ask.

Comment: I added it to the bottom of the page like this <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

     $('#reg-form').submit(function() {
         var newSrc = $('#avatar1').attr('src');
         $('[name=avatar]').val(newSrc);
     });

});
</script> But it makes the page appear blank and my editor says there is a syntax error?